# Why do texture based vs. rectangle based physics bodies intersect the edge loop?

Tags: swift, game-physics, skspritenode, skphysicsbody, skscene

In my `SKScene` class I have several texture based physics bodies in my game, e.g.:

```
object1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "object_name1"), size: CGSize(width: 113, height: 107))

object2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "object_name2"), size: CGSize(width: 113, height: 65))
```

etc.

I also have rectangle based physics bodies, e.g.:

```
object3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: object3.size)

object4.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: object4.size)
```

etc.

I have defined the game boundary as follows:

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
```

I have set up all the appropriate physics properties for each object (`SKSpriteNode`).

The problem I am having is that the texture based physics bodies go beyond the game boundary as I move them, and can potentially fall out of the scene, but the rectangle based ones remain constrained by the boundary (as expected).

Any idea(s) why?